# Jenkins spins endlessly at the end of a test run

Tags: ruby, cucumber, jenkins

I'm running a suite of cucumber tests and it'll go though the entire suite just fine. When it gets to the end where cucumber says X scenarios passed X failed etc etc Jenkins will spin endlessly here. I can stop the project and the output that was done is saved fine, but to get the endless loop to stop I have to close the build prematurely. The odd thing is I have another project that has the same settings, running off the same server, only running the tests that I expect to fail and this suite runs and finishes normally. I'm curious if anyone has seen this issue or would know some of the commands that I can use to figure out what's causing the hangup? I'm running my tests through a windows batch commands to launch my cucumber tests formatting/outputting to an html file.

Let me know if there's any other data that would help with this. I've googled a bit on it but didn't see anything related to my issue (could be using the wrong wording possibly though).

Thanks

Comment: Which OS are you running on? Can you confirm that the process of cucumber died and the loop is in Jenkins?

Comment: Windows 7 X64. I can't confirm that, however it runs fine if I run that same batch command in the console so I would assume that it's not an issue with cucumber but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when the program you are running returns error code of 259 which accidentally corresponds `STILL_ALIVE` error code.

To detect whether this is the case, execute `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` immediately after running cucumber tests.

Comment: I added that to the end of my batch file but it still just sat there and spun. As a side note I think it might have something to do with publishing the HTML report but I'm looking into that now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to latency between the executor and the master because the junit xml results are transfered by SCP one by one.